# How to CONCAT two column value into a JSON format?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'd like to `CONCAT` two column value into one string in `string` in `JSON` format. However I have problem with the quote and double quote in the query. How do I fix my query  so it success produce the expected result?

```
$concat = "CONCAT('{"CODE":"pm_r.CODE","NAME":"pm_r.NAME"}') AS `JSON`"
$query  = $this->db->query(
    'SELECT pm_r.ID_REQUIREMENT, '.$concat.'FROM `pm_requirement` `pm_r`'
);
```

The expected out should be:

```
ID_REQUIREMENT   JSON
ID001            {"CODE":"001","NAME":"Shane"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a json array using concat with MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000248/creating-a-json-array-using-concat-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid quoting clashes, a solution is to use a [php `HEREDOC` string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

I also fixed you `CONCAT`, where  the names of the column to concatenate should be separated from the fixed parts of the string.

```
$query  = $this->db->query(<<<EOT
    SELECT 
        pm_r.ID_REQUIREMENT,
        CONCAT('{"CODE":"', pm_r.CODE, '","NAME":"', pm_r.NAME, '"}') AS `JSON`
        FROM `pm_requirement` `pm_r`
EOT
);
```

Answer (score -1):

$concat = "CONCAT('{"CODE":"pm_r.CODE","NAME":"pm_r.NAME"}') AS `JSON`"

Try change the $concat query like below :
$concat =  "CONCAT('{"CODE":"', pm_r.CODE ,'","NAME":"', pm_r.NAME, '"}') AS JSON"

Please look like similar to my case, and it can make it become json info, please take a look below screenshot from my database query :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVjNt.png)